# Can I use Laravel's database layer standalone?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

For some time now I have been looking towards using a php framework for my work. I've been writing procedural style until recently and is still trying to find my way around the oop world/style.
I figured that a php framework would help me write better code and I'm pretty sure I'll lean towards the Laravel project in a near future.

Right now I'm in need of a database layer that I can use in my existing code. I use mysqli with prepared statements right now, as it was easy for me to implement (using MySQL before).

I've been looking at http://medoo.in as an "easy" way to use a pdo wrapper/class but the lack of activity on the support page, and the fact that I'm working on using Laravel in the future, made me wonder if I could use the Laravel database layer now for my existing code.

Could this be done and would it make sense or am I misunderstanding and mixing concepts of code styling?

Comment: I'm using Eloquent standalone for a year and I can say: that's a terrible idea, please go with a real ORM like Doctrine and avoid massive suffering.

Comment: The Medoo project is still active. You can check out the project on GitHub https://github.com/catfan/Medoo.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

IMO it's absolutely valid to transition to an OOP approach step by step.

To your question:

Yes, you can use Eloquent standalone.

Here is the packagist site: https://packagist.org/packages/illuminate/database
Add `"illuminate/database": "5.0.*@dev"` to your `composer.json` and run `composer update`.
Now you'll need to bootstrap Eloquent. (https://github.com/illuminate/database)

The following is copied from the repo's readme:

Usage Instructions

First, create a new "Capsule" manager instance. Capsule aims to make configuring the library for usage outside of the Laravel framework as easy as possible.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => 'password',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);

// Set the event dispatcher used by Eloquent models... (optional)
use Illuminate\Events\Dispatcher;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;
$capsule->setEventDispatcher(new Dispatcher(new Container));

// Set the cache manager instance used by connections... (optional)
$capsule->setCacheManager(...);

// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Once the Capsule instance has been registered. You may use it like so:

Using The Query Builder

```
$users = Capsule::table('users')->where('votes', '>', 100)->get();
```

Other core methods may be accessed directly from the Capsule in the same manner as from the DB facade:

```
$results = Capsule::select('select * from users where id = ?', array(1));
```

Using The Schema Builder

```
Capsule::schema()->create('users', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Using The Eloquent ORM

```
class User extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {}

$users = User::where('votes', '>', 1)->get();
```

For further documentation on using the various database facilities this library provides, consult the Laravel framework documentation.

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply.. i wanted to know if we could create an alias to Capsule::schema() set to Schema, so it can be used the same way as in Laravel ie Schema::Model->action() or Schema::table()->action() ?

Comment: You could create a `Schema` class and redirect all static method calls to `Capsule::schema()->$method` with `__callStatic`.

Comment: How do you run migrations, or is that not possible?