# Laravel tinker in multi-tenant environment

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multi-tenant

I am developing a multi-tenant application using *Laravel-5.2*
Each tenant will have a separate database. Each tenant has their separate subdomain. I detect tenants using their subdomains.

I have setup models `Tenant` and `DatabaseConnection` where `Tenant hasOne DatabaseConnection` and `DatabaseConnection belongsTo Tenant`.
The DB connections for tenants are set dynamically from `BeforeMiddleware`. These work perfectly well.

Now I want to use `artisan tinker` for the tenants. But if I run `php artisan tinker` it connects to the `Tenant` whose DB credentials are present in the `.env` file.

So I am trying to make a console command for the same. Here's what I have achieved so far.

```
class ClientTinker extends Command {

    protected $name = 'cdb:tinker';

    public function fire()
    {
        // get the subdomain
        $subdomain = $this->argument('subdomain');

        // get the client
        $client = Tenant::whereSubdomain($subdomain)->first();

        $connection = $client->databaseConnection();
        // $connection contains the database server, database name, user name, and password.
        // dynamically set connections here. *How?*
        ...

        // *I need to call tinker here. How?* 
    }

    protected function getArguments()
    {
        return [
            ['subdomain', InputArgument::REQUIRED, 'Subdomain of the tenant.'],
        ];
    }
```

So how do I set the DB connections for specific tenant and how do I run tinker?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31281669/how-do-i-connect-to-different-databases-at-run-time

Comment: Are you trying to make a console command to `tinker` into a specific tenant?

Comment: Yes. So that I don't have to keep changing DB credentials in `.env` file before running `tinker`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you get the `$connection` variable in `fire()`, do this

```
DB::purge('mysql');

Config::set('database.connections.mysql.host', $connection->server);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', $connection->database);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.username', $connection->username);
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.password', $connection->password);
// I am assuming the variable names in $connection object here, as you have not specified them in your question.

Artisan::call('tinker');
```

See if this works for you.